# Android popup menu display causes RecyclerView scroll up

Tags: android, scroll, popup, android-recyclerview

I have Android popup menu displayed on menu `Button` click in item in `RecyclerView`.

It worked fine earlier but after recent library update (24.2.0) popup menu display  scrolls `RecyclerView` upwards. Menu is displayed correctly at anchor point but `RecyclerView` scrolls up leaving gap between item and pop-up menu.

Any clues to help resolve?

Comment: This is solved by using android.widget.PopupMenu instead of android.support.v7.widget.PopupMenu. Looks like bug in support library

Answer (score 0):

Wow. I was running into the same issue and @android developer answer is indeed the correct sollution. The popupMenu from the support library needs updating